# Getting a Windows container talking to a Linux container running on WSL2

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2

I have two containers running on separate docker engines:

1. A Windows container running on a Windows local docker installation (not docker desktop)
2. A Linux database container running on a WSL2 docker installation on the same host.

I want the Windows container to be able to connect to the database in the Linux container running on WSL2.

The issue I'm having is that I'm not very experienced in networking so I don't know how to set this up. The containers use different virtual ethernet adapters:

- WSL2 container - `vEthernet (WSL)` (with an IP like `172.31.x.x`)
- Windows container - `vEthernet (nat)` (with an IP like `172.21.x.x`).
- Then there is also a `vEthernet (Default Switch)` that I could use for the Windows container if I wanted to (by adding `--network "Default Switch"` to the docker run command), but it does not seem to be what is used by default.

All of this works fine, the host can ping both containers and both containers can ping the host and stuff outside the host, so there is nothing wrong there. My issue is that they are on different networks (obviously) and I have no idea how to connect them together.

What I would have expected to work were to connect to the database via `127.0.0.1:3306` (3306 being the published port on the database container), but I can't get it to work without using the IP address of the WSL2 environment. While that isn't an issue from the host, it is an issue from the Windows container.

An idea I had to solve that was if one could use `docker run --network host` when starting the Windows container to have it on the host network, but `host` doesn't show up when running `docker network list` (it does exist on the WSL2 side though, but that doesn't help me).

Comment: To connect to database you should use WSL2 ip address in your api and publish database port in your db container

Comment: The database port is published: 
`docker container port test-db`
`3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3306`
`3306/tcp -> :::3306`
And as I said, the containers are on different networks, so using the WSL2 ip address is not going to work.

Comment: what is WSL2 ip address ? you can ping WSL2 ip address to check if it is accusable in your api machine or container

Comment: it's possible to ping from the host system, but not from the windows container.